# django python file storage

Tags: python, django, upload, disk

I would like to upload a file, parse it to .txt and then store it in the disk via a django application. I've tried quiet a few things that didn't work. First I want to make the storage work. Here's my code. I would appreciate any help.

**Index.html**

```
<form name='F' action='AjoutTelechargement' method='POST' 
enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                    {% csrf_token %}
<input type="file" name="filedir" style="color:white" size="100" >
<input type="submit" class="btn .btn-ajouter btn-xl page-scroll" 
value="Ajouter" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js">
</script>
<script>
   function myFun() {
       $.get('AjoutTelechargement/'
              , "value":"get_the_value_from_web"}
              , function(ret) {
                    return ret;
                });
   }
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

key_store = FileSystemStorage(location='myFiles/')

class FileUpload(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(storage=key_store, upload_to='myFiles/%Y-%m-%d', 
    blank=False, null=False)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from omicCV import views as omicCV_views
from blog import views as blog_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', omicCV_views.index),
    url(r'^admin', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^AjoutTelechargement$', blog_views.AjoutTelechargement),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import FileUpload


@csrf_exempt
def AjoutTelechargement(request):

if request.method == 'POST':
  form = FileUpload(request.POST, request.FILES)
  form.save()
  return HttpResponse("done!")
```

I am trying to parse the uploaded pdf files to txt:

def AjoutTelechargement(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['filedir']:
    filedir = request.FILES['filedir']
    fs = FileSystemStorage(location='myFiles/')
    for filename in filedir:
        path=filename
        if b"pdf" in filename:
            print("repère2")
            head, tail = os.path.split(path)

            var = b"\\"

            tail = tail.replace(b".pdf", b".txt")

            name = head + var + tail

            content = ""

            pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(path, bool('rb'))

            for i in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
                content += pdf.getPage(i).extractText()
                print(strftime("%H:%M:%S"), " pdf  -> txt ")
                with (name, 'a') as f:
                    text_file_doc = {"file_name": "test_file_name.txt",
                                     "contents": f.write(content.encode('ascii', 'replace').decode('UTF-8'))}
                    fs.save(filedir.name, text_file_doc)
                    return HttpResponse("done!")

    return HttpResponse("undone")
```

But got this error in this line: pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(path, bool('rb'))

Exception Value:
**'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'**
Exception Location: C:\Users\RAHMA\omicroneCV\lib\site-packages\PyPDF2\pdf.py in read, line 1689

Comment: "First I want to make the storage work." I would start by registering your model in the admin page and making sure uploads work as intended there. You'll also probably find it easier to use django's built in forms when rendering the form on your template.

Comment: No sorry I actually made the uploads work and I am able now to store the files in the filesystem but i am still stuck in trying to parse them to .txt before storing them. The code is above with the error.

Comment: `PdfFileReader(stream, strict=True, warndest=None, overwriteWarnings=True)`

Looks like you've set strict to True. I've never used the package so I don't know if that's what you want, but maybe it'll work if you disable it? From the documentation https://pythonhosted.org/PyPDF2/PdfFileReader.html:


`strict (bool) – Determines whether user should be warned of all problems and also causes some correctable problems to be fatal. Defaults to True.`

Comment: I also have to caution you against letting a user specify a file system location through post. It could definitely be big security problem if you aren't very careful about cleansing user inputs.

Comment: I tried it but still didn't work, thanks though! I also tried other packages like pdfminer2 or pyPdf but in vain.